# Distinct failing with order by having CASE statment in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, sql-order-by, case

I am facing an issue while getting distinct records from table

My Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%S%'
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN name LIKE 'S%' THEN 0 else 1 end,name
```

Error: [SQL01214] ORDER BY EXPRESSION IS NOT VALID
Error detail: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql0214.htm

I tried by writing subquery and corelated subquery but no luck

Need help to get alternate SQL query..

Comment: Can you share the SQL with the subquery you tried and the error it produces too please?

Comment: SELECT  name FROM employee WHERE name IN (
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%S%')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name like 'S%' then 0 else 1, name 
-- same error

Comment: Hi Sham, please have a look at my answer.  Maybe one of the two options will get you working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation link from IBM](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql0214.htm) you provided, your error appears to be caused by the following condition:

> DISTINCT is specified in the select clause and the expression cannot be matched exactly with an expression in the select list. This reason code occurs only when clause-type is ORDER BY.

In other words, you used `DISTINCT` on the `name` field but then also tried to use `name` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

You can try the following subquery to get around a potential problem with the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT name FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%S%'
) t
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN t.name LIKE 'S%' THEN 0 else 1 end, t.name
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your quick response, 2nd query works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a common table expression to order by a case statement in a distinct select.

```
with cte as (
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%S%'
)
select * from cte
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN name LIKE 'S%' THEN 0 else 1 end,name
```